# Ordered Dict, preserve initial Order

Tags: python, data-structures

**Ordered Dict:**

```
import collections
d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

The above example shows how to order a dict, which is unsupported by nature. However, how can i preserve the initial order rather then sorting by key or value?

Comment: Then don't use a regular `dict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial order *is* preserved for an `OrderedDict`, so just put it straight in and bypass the regular dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])
>>> od
OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you initialized regular dict with your items the order is gone. So just initialize *ordered* dict in initial order:

```
import collections as co

co.OrderedDict([(a, b) for a, b in list_of_pairs])
# or
d = co.OrderedDict()
for a, b in list_of_pairs:
    d[a] = b
```

Answer (score 1):

Already regular `dict` has no order when you defining.`sort` on `dict` is actually not sorting dict.It is sorting the `list` containing `tuples` of `(key, value)` pairs.

```
d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
s = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])
>>>s
[('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)]
```

This is `sorted` list of `tuples` .`key = lambda t: t[0]` is returning `2nd` element of tuple.So sorting based on `2nd` element of `tuple`

```
new_d = dict(s)
>>>new_d.items()
[('orange', 2), ('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
```

That is order disappears.Inoder to maintain order, `OrderedDict` is used.

For example

```
>>>OrderedDict({"a":5})
OrderedDict([('a', 5)])
```

This is also maintaining `list of tuples`.

So you have to `pass` a sorted `list of tuple`

```
>>>OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])
OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])
```

Comment: The only thing i don't like about OrderedDict is, that the result is a List Representation, which loses the JSON characteristic. Thank you for the detailled expalanation!

Comment: No worry, i think all operation on `dict` is possible on `defaultdict` even `list representation`